# Is there a way to select Non-Planar Faces?

Tags: mesh, faces, selection-tools

The "Clean up" toolbox can detect non-planar faces and split them. But I'd like to have a way to view them first! Is there an easy method of mass-selecting non-planar faces (like a trait selection)?

Thanks in advance, I hope someone helps me out!

Comment: Could you add a screencapture of your mesh?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script to run in edit mode,  It looks at all faces with > 3 vertices, defines a plane from the first 3 verts `[v.co for v in ngon.verts[:3]]` as input coords to determine its [normal](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane) and `ngon.verts[0].co` is a point on the plane

If [absolute distance from rest of vertices in ngon to defined plane](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane) is less than some tolerance the face is planar.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils.geometry import (
            distance_point_to_plane,
            normal)

context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
mesh = obj.data

TOL = 0.001

# select None
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
ngons = [f for f in bm.faces if len(f.verts) > 3]

for ngon in ngons:
    # define a plane from first 3 points
    co = ngon.verts[0].co
    norm = normal([v.co for v in ngon.verts[:3]])

    ngon.select =  not all(
        [abs(distance_point_to_plane(v.co, co, norm)) < TOL
        for v in ngon.verts[3:]])

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

Result of running script with TOL = 0.1 on mesh made of cylinder, uv sphere, torus and monkey primitives.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the script, I ran it but sadly it didn't help the cause much. Reason being - it selects way more faces that it thinks are non-planar, but at the same time Blender's cleanup finds far less of those.

Comment: The script has a tolerance TOL which is the distance from the vert to the "face plane",  just like split non planar faces operator has an angle_limit (default 5 degs).  Perhaps I could change up to check angle rather than distance to match clean up.  Added a pic of result of running script using TOL = 0.1. It selects pretty much all the monkey if TOL = 0.00001 and none of the others. It selects no faces after "split non planar faces" clean up.... I'm **happy** with it.

Comment: Very interesting, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile the 3D-Print Toolbox provides this functionality out of the box:

- activate the add-on `Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox`
- select your object
- open the `N`-panel
- click the `3D-Print` tab
- click `Check-All` (or `Distorted` under Checks)
- make sure you are in edit mode
- click the `Non-Flat Faces`button.

[image: screenshot of 3D-Print Toolbox]