# Triangular Wrinkles on faces?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to make a low-poly head for an animation, but whenever I render the object, weird cuts/wrinkles are appearing on the face (see Below)

[image]

Here's the solid view

[image]

[image]

How do I make those cuts disappear?

Comment: The main problem is that you are dealing with non-planar faces, compounded by the use of n-gons (faces with more than 4 vertices).  Try some of the solutions on these links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/how-to-make-all-quads-or-ngons-on-your-mesh-planar-2d and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69600/is-there-a-way-to-select-non-planar-faces and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky

Comment: Thanks alot! :) deleting and dissolving some of the vertices did help with the issue

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. Other users with a similar problem can learn then from your experience. Read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I'll make sure to answer it as soon as I can find a more appropriate fix for the issue itself.